# connecting display with only usb-c ports to macbook pro 2014 (no usb-c ports)

Tags: display, usb

I'm inspecting a 4K monitor that has USB-C port only. I'd like to connect it to macbook pro 2014, which doesn't have an USB-C type of port.

I found some adapters that can convert between ports, but I am sceptic whether signal can be upgraded from older usb-3 port to usb-c? Is there any data loss?

**Background:**
As you might know, issues with external displays and Apple devices are quite common. For this particular model, Apple has an official site in where it explains that [this particular monitor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207447) is not compatible with devices that are older than 2015.

I am curious, if this is just because port incompatibly and whether this can be solved by using adapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot connect the monitor to an USB A port (i.e. for example the non-USB-C USB 3 port you mention).

The monitor uses the so called "Alternate Mode" part of the USB-C connector. Essentially it means that the USB-C cable in addition to USB carries a seperate signal - for example DisplayPort as in this case.

Older USB connectors and cables do not have support for "Alternate Mode" and thus no adapters can be made.